# insert column depend value in specific array

Tags: php, arrays

How can I insert a value into `LainLain`, but only for row `others` at `Nama` column.

This is what happens in my table right now :

```
 Nama     |     LainLain
 value1   |     num1
 value1   |     num1
 value1   |     num1
 value1   |     num1
 others   |     num1
```

What is what I want to achieve:

```
 Nama     |     LainLain
 value1   |    
 value1   |   
 value1   |   
 value1   | 
 others   |     num1
```

**CODE:**

```
$sign_symptoms     = $_POST['sign_symptoms'];
$countSignSymptoms = count($_POST['sign_symptoms']);
for ( $i = 0; $i < $countSignSymptoms; $i++){
    if ($sign_symptoms[$i] == "others") {
        $other_symptoms == " ";
        $pdo->exec("insert into simka_simptom(IDMohon, Nama, LainLain) values ('".$IDMohon."','".$sign_symptoms[$i]."','".$other_symptoms."')");
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: have you done anything for this ?

Comment: @AnandPatel a already try but what i've got is like the example 1.

Comment: i mean please paste your code that you have done so far

Comment: already paste...sorry because im a bit confuse @AnandPatel

Comment: you are trying to insert new record right ?

Comment: @AnandPatel yes..its for new insert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
    $sign_symptoms     = $_POST['sign_symptoms'];
    $countSignSymptoms = count($_POST['sign_symptoms']);
    for ( $i = 0; $i < $countSignSymptoms; $i++)
    {
        if ($sign_symptoms[$i] == "others") 
        {
            $other_symptoms = "num1";

        }
        else
        {
            $other_symptoms = "";
        }
        $pdo->exec("insert into simka_simptom(IDMohon, Nama, LainLain) values           
        ('".$IDMohon."','".$sign_symptoms[$i]."','".$other_symptoms."')");
    }
```

Comment: nice to hear that your problem is solved happy coding :)